# how to create grails project through windows command promt

Tags: grails, groovy

How to create Grails project through windows command prompt?
In Grails Documents it says to use Posh-GVM.But i want to know how to use Posh_GVM.

Comment: Posh GVM is located here - https://github.com/flofreud/posh-gvm/ - did you try it and receive an error? (if so post the error)

Comment: You want create grails project windows command right?

Comment: Also check out start.grails.org

Comment: @rijas pk Have you set GRAILS_HOME in windows?

Comment: @Dipak thoke -yea ,i want create grails project through windows command prompt.Environmental variables are already created,and i created project via ggts.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the JDK is properly installed and JAVA_HOME environment variable is defined. To make sure your JDK is installed, you can open a command prompt and enter

java -version

Make sure appropriate Grails files as downloaded and GRAILS_HOME environment variable is defined. To make sure Grails is installed, you can open a command prompt and enter

```
 grails -version
```

Once you have successfully installed JDK and Grails, go to the folder where you want to create your Grails app and type

```
 grails
 create-app com.example.yourappname
```

Answer (score 0):

I have consider that you have set JAVA_HOME && GRAILS HOME

**Then check for JAVA_HOME && GRAILS_HOME**

Type this into your command prompt :

```
JAVA -version
```

then check for

**GRAILS_HOME**

If  both are shown their version else you reset your ENVIRONMENT variable again.

If you want create grails app through command prompt :

Go to cmd prompt :

create directory using following command:

```
mkdir grails_app
```

Then go to grails_app directory following command:

```
cd grails_app
```

Then,

Type following command to create the grails application in using command prompt:

```
grails create-app helloworld
```

Here,

**helloworld - Name of grails application**

For more details you can use following document :

http://docs.grails.org/2.4.4/guide/gettingStarted.html#creatingAnApplication

Hope this will help you create grails app through command prompt

Comment: as a wrote the create command error "

C:\Users\se399>cd grails-app

C:\Users\se399\grails-app>grails create-app helloworld
'grails' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\se399\grails-app>"  occured

Comment: It means you have not set grails home

Comment: please set grails enivoroment variable first then try it will work

Comment: http://www.evoketechnologies.com/blog/setup-grails-framework-windows/ use this link set grails ENV varraible.

Comment: @rijaspk can you just up vote ans(+1) my answer so that others can refer this answer