# How to configure Grails for Netbeans?

Tags: java, grails, netbeans

I am trying to configure Grails in Netbeans.

- Grails version:3.2
- Netbeans: 8.2
- JDK: 1.8
- OS: Windows 10

I have install and configured environment path and other stuffs. I can create and run project from the Command Prompt. But I can not create project from netbeans.

```
Warning |
Unrecognized flag: non-interactive.
Error |
Specify an application name or use --inplace to create an application in the current directory
```

This error is showing, to create project from Netbeans. I can run the created project though. I have already added Groovy plugin.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time!

Comment: done.. can you help me in this regard?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you are doing anything incorrectly. I have an environment very similar to yours (Grails version: 3.3.2, Netbeans: 8.2, JDK: 8u151, OS: Windows 10) and I see the same error: *Specify an application name or use --inplace...*

This is a known issue with NetBeans 8.2 that has already been bug reported; see [Bug 258407 - Error when creating a Grails 3.1.x project](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=258407). The problem has been confirmed to exist in Grails releases 3.1.0 up to 3.1.4, but I see the same issue in 3.3.2, and there is no fix for NetBeans 8.2.

However, I successfully created a Groovy/Grails application using JDK 8u151 with a DEV release of NetBeans which you can download from here: http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/

Note the caveat that comes with using DEV releases of NetBeans:

> These builds are still under development and could contain defects
>   that lead to data loss. They are meant for evaluation of new features.
>   As always, be sure to back up your changes if you use these builds on
>   your production code.

As long as you can you can live with that situation, using a DEV release is your (only) solution for creating Grails 3.x applications in NetBeans.

One final point: unlike NetBeans 8.2, DEV releases of NetBeans support Java 9 as well as Java 8, but don't use Java 9 when creating a Groovy/Grails applications. It won't work for a completely unrelated reason.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Windows 8 and Grails 3.3.8, but the following worked for me:

1. Create the project using system command line (I used instructions in this page: [how to create grails project through windows command promt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44001436/how-to-create-grails-project-through-windows-command-promt)).
2. Import the project to Netbeans 8.2 by clicking on File > Open Project... and selecting the project folder.

Comment: open project does not work for me. When I select the grails application directory (e.g. helloworld), It wont let me edit the project name, its greyed out, and the "open project" button does nothing.  the subdirectories I see when I open the grails helloworld application dir, is gradle, grails-app and src.

Comment: @JohnLittle, are you using Netbeans 8.2?

Answer (score 1):

This solution works for me (Mac OS)

1) Open de console inside Netbeans

2) Navigate to your GRAILS_HOME/bin

3) Type grails create-app [YOUR_NAME_APP] --profile=web (rest-api, etc)

4) The project must be created at GRAILS_HOME/bin/[YOUR_NAME_APP]

5) Do not try to import into Netbeans instead of it Open the project

6) Start coding!

You can move the folder GRAILS_HOME/bin/[YOUR_NAME_APP] to the Netbeans workspace before open the project.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I am using netbeans 9 and grails 3.3.8 (dont use 3.3.9, its broken), and it works like a dream.  I can create domain classes etc. from the menus in netbeans, run, debug etc.  THe only thing I had to do was manually install the grails plugin for netbeans, and configure my grails paths etc.  The answer on how to set this up is here: [how to open a grails 3.3 app in netbeans 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52826163/how-to-open-a-grails-3-3-app-in-netbeans-9)

The only thing I cant get to work (and its a bit of a show stopper), is multi-module projects (i.e. a grails app which depends on a grails plugin). I can run them, but netbeans does not recognise any of the imports so there is no code completion and it shows all files are having errors.  What a shame, as appart from this, netbeans has very good grails support.

Note, I always create projects on the command line, e.g. "grails create-app myapp ...", then simply use the open project menu in netbeans and it instantly recognises them as grails.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have gradle plugin installed for netbeans. Then go to File -> Open Project.

You should see the project shown by netbeans as a gradle project.