# Grails 3.x Will Not Activate in Netbeans 10.0

Tags: grails

I want to use Grails 3.x with Netbeans 10.0. When I downloaded Netbeans 10 I ran netbeans64.exe (I'm assuming this is for 64-bit machines?). And Groovy was not installed from the Plugins section (but was available for installing). So I checked the box to install it but it will not activate. I only get the option to Uninstall.
[image: Greyed out Groovy]

What am I missing here to get this working? I have grails 3.3.6 installed if that matters.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48127035/how-to-configure-grails-for-netbeans

Comment: @Vahid That thread references an older version of Netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

Having the same problem with NetBeans 10.0 and Groovy, I downloaded "Gradle Support" plugin from http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/44510/gradle-support
and installed it into NetBeans (Tools -> Plugins -> Downloaded -> Add Plugin...). After that I could open my old Gradle project. Hope this helps.