# NetBeans-11 Can not setup for using Grails

Tags: grails, groovy, netbeans

Using NB-8.2 In the dialog - "Tools/Options/Miscellaneous/Groovy" You could enter the location of your Grails-installation" but know with NB11 that input field is missing.
I've read the question "Can not run Grails project from NetBeans" where you where suggested to remove all plugins regarding Gradle and Groovy and then reinstall them, which I tried but it didn't help.

I tried it on NB11.1 and uninstalled the following plugins:
Gradle, Gradle and Groovy and Pure Groovy Project.
Gradle and Grovy including "Gradle and Groovy" couldn't be uninstalled - only deactivated but the last one "Pure Groovy project" could be uninstalled. But afterwards I can not find that plugin to reinstall. So where can I find that?

Now I have installed NB11.2 but still the same problem.
So where to go now?

Answer (score 2):

I got this working on a fresh installation of NetBeans 11.2 under Windows 10 using Grails 3.3.11. However, there are some significant limitations because the approach essentially only recreates the Grails environment that worked with NetBeans 8.2:

**Initial Status**

1. There are no *Groovy*, *Grails* or *Gradle* entries on the project wizard menu (**File > New Project...**).
2. **Tools > Plugins > Installed Plugins** shows version *1.38* of *Groovy* is *active*, and version *1.2* of *Groovy and Gradle* is *inactive*.
3. The **Tools > Options > Miscellaneous > Groovy** tab shows that there is no **Grails Home** field available, as mentioned in the OP.

**NetBeans 11.2 Changes**

4. First, note that you **must** set JDK 1.8 as the default platform for NetBeans 11.2. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2809447/2985643) for details on how to do that. Of course you can still create projects using other JDK versions when the default platform is JDK 8.
5. Also note that taking the obvious step of activating *Groovy and Gradle 1.2* does not help, and subsequently restarting NetBeans does not change anything, so discard that approach.
6. This is the initial version of the relevant plugins: *Gradle 1.2*, *Groovy and Gradle 1.2* and *Groovy 1.38*.
7. Delete all three plugins. Netbeans will restart.
8. The **Groovy** tab is now missing from **Tools > Options > Miscellaneous**.
9. Select **Tools > Plugins > Settings**, and click the **Add** button, which will open the *Update Center Customizer* screen.
10. Enter *Grails Plugins* in the **Name** field (or any other descriptive value you prefer ), and `http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/8.2/uc/final/distribution/catalog.xml.gz` 
    in the **URL** field, and click **OK**.
11. Ensure that only the new entry for *Grails Plugins* is checked on the **Settings** tab, then go to the **Available Plugins** tab.
12. Select the entry for *Groovy and Grails 1.34.1*, and click **Install**. NetBeans
    will restart.
13. After NetBeans restarts, select **Tools > Options > Miscellaneous** and click the **Groovy** tab. There is now a **Grails Home** field available, so set it to your Grails installation:

    [image: GrailsHome]

**Creating a Grails Project**

13. Select **File > New Project > Groovy > Grails Application** to create a Grails project.
14. You will get this error:

    > Warning |
    >
    > Unrecognized flag: non-interactive.
    >
    > Error |
    >
    > Specify an application name or use --inplace to create an application in the current directory
15. One workaround for that is to create your Grails project from the command line using *grails create-app...*, then open that project in NetBeans. See [this helpful SO answer for full details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53256300/2985643).
16. Once that is done, you can develop, build and run your Grails application in NetBeans 11.2:

    [image: GrailsWebPage]

**Notes**

1. After doing all the steps above, there is no Gradle entry under **File > New Project...**, and if you attempt to install the Gradle plugin to address that, you will get the following warning:

   [image: InstallGradlePlugin]

   Don't proceed, because reinstalling Groovy 1.38 (which you deleted in step #6 above) will prevent Grails from working. So be aware that this solution for Grails prevents you from creating freestanding Gradle projects in NetBeans 11.2 using the Project Wizard. Also, to be clear, the only plugin you should have installed to get Grails working is *Groovy and Grails* version *1.34.1*. You do not need any other plugins containing the words *"Groovy"* or *"Gradle"* installed.
2. I also tried creating a Grails project using Grails 4.0.1, but got the error "*Could not instantiate global transform class org.spockframework.compiler.SpockTransform...*". There are workarounds suggested for that error on SO. I didn't pursue them but since Grails 3.x does not work with any JDK > 8, and Grails 4.x supports JDKs > 8, you may want to pursue this issue yourself.
3. You can download and install [the "Pure Groovy" plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/49928/?show=true) from here. Although it's old, it still seems to work fine, and it will add a "Groovy Project" entry in the Project Wizard:

   [image: GrailsProject]
4. Also see [does netbeans 11 support grails?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55543696/2985643), although that question was for NetBeans 11.0 rather than 11.2.

Comment: I want to thank you for a great answer but I'm sorry to say that it didn't work. You see, I can't uninstall any of the groovy  plugins, only deacitivate them. When I did that and then added the new updatecenter for NB-8.2 nothing happends. No more available plugins appear even if I restart NB. But a funny thing is that I can add an existing project and run it without specifying what GRAILS-version to use. Of course it uses the version that the project was built on. Even version 4.01 works. But it would be nice to have GRAILS-project available from the menu.

Comment: Well, it can run projects but not maintain them theres no menues for grails and if you want to create a new domain class - you can't. So why am I not able to uninstall those groovy plugins?

Comment: Finally I found a working solution in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54490958/groovy-and-grail-plugin-is-missing-in-netbeans-ide-9